# como remover todos os resquícios de dados no cache do google busca?

Tags: html, html-meta-tag

já desabilitei a indexação (robots.txt) e já fiz a inserção da `meta tag` (`<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`) no `<head>` da página, porém quando eu procuro no meu site para ver se há algum resquício de dado no google busca, percebo que há várias informações alí ainda.

há uma outra maneira de remover **todas** informações do meu site de uma vez só? eu sei da existência deste link:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

porém, é necessário adicionar link por link.

Comment: Você quer remover seu site da busca do Google?

Comment: Quando você fez esses ajustes?

Comment: eu fiz as modificações no meio de outubro. quando eu pesquiso "nome do meu site + nome da pessoa" os dados aparecem em forma de cache (são dados antes de outubro). são alguns dados sigilosos.

Comment: Tentou testar em navegador de outras pessoas que nunca acessaram o site?

Comment: como assim? é no google search que faço a busca

Comment: O tempo de reindexação pode ser de até 1 ou 2 semanas pelo que eu me recordo. Se informe melhor a respeito disso, mas te garanto que as modificações não acontecem no ato, você terá que esperar alguns dias...

Comment: não tem mais nenhum dado do dia 20 de outubro para cá (quando fiz a indexação), o problema são os dados já antigos, todos ainda estão lá e são bastante. se eu remover um por um, vai dar um trabalhão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apenas como observação, não é possível dizer com toda a certeza o como o google funciona, apenas podemos interpretar as informações na documentação no google então estarei apenas deixando uma sugestão do que pode estar causando isso

### O que sabemos pela documentação

Primeiro de tudo, o robots.txt indica apenas que o google não deve indexar o seu site, porém se o site já está indexado a documentação não indica que isso seria o suficiente par remover este conteúdo.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608

O uso da meta `noindex` vai impedir que o google de indexar o seu site, porém para isso ele precisa poder enxergar esta tag, se você usar o robots para bloquear a página ele nunca vai ver esta tag.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710

### Então o que pode estar acontecendo

Uma possibilidade é de que o google ao tentar buscar conteúdo atualizado de seu site se depare com o robots.txt que pede para ele não indexar o site, e como o google respeita seu pedido ele nem mesmo chega a ver se o conteúdo de sua página mudou.

Porém o google já possui uma página sua indexada, e esta página que ele possui indexada no cache dele não possui nenhuma informação de que ela não deve estar lá, o que pode ser o que está fazendo o google manter sua página nas pesquisas dele.

### O que poderia resolver o problema

Talvez o que você precise fazer não é impedir o crawler do google de verificar o seu site, ao contrário talvez permitir ele fazer isso temporariamente possa fazer com que seu problema seja resolvido.

Remover o robots.txt para permitir que ele tente buscar estas mesmas páginas que ele já possui indexadas vai fazer com que ele encontre a meta `noindex`, e permitindo que ele atualize seu cache, removendo a página antiga.

Caso isso funcione e não apareçam mais resultados das suas páginas você pode voltar o robots.txt para diminuir as requisições ao seu site vindas do crawler do google.